# Converting vb function to c# in winform app

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to convert a previously written .net winform app from vb to c# and I'm running into trouble with a web send function.  How can I convert this into c#?

```
Public Shared Function Send(p_ipAddress As String, p_action As String, p_page As String, p_body As String, p_filePath As String) As String

        Dim objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        'objHttp.setTimeouts(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)  '-- Timeout

        objHttp.Open(p_action, sUrl, False)

        If t_fileContent.Length > 0 Then
            objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & t_multipart_boundary)
        Else
            t_fileContent.Append(p_body)
            objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        End If

        objHttp.Send(t_fileContent.ToString())

        If objHttp.Status = 200 Then
            Return objHttp.responseText
        End If

        Return ""

    End Function
```

The HTTP object is what I'm having trouble translating into c#.  I dont' know whether I need to use a http client, http web request, I'm fairly new to web calls.

**EDIT** I've shortened the code to specifically what I'm not sure about, removing the fluff.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715662/asynchronous-msxml2-xmlhttp-request-in-code-behind

Comment: I would consider leaving it in vb but moving the code to a library project that you can reference from c#.

Comment: Is `var objHttp = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP");` all you need?

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`

Comment: But there are proper .NET classes that handle sending over HTTP. It would be better to rewrite using those.

Comment: I added that, but it doesn't provide for the open, setRequestHeaders,or Send methods associated to it.

Comment: @Enigmativity, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DrewJackson - Sure there are - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022965/adding-http-headers-to-httpclient

Comment: Try this: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static string Send(string p_ipAddress, string p_action, string p_page, string p_body, string p_filePath)
{
    dynamic objHttp = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP");
    // objHttp.setTimeouts(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)  '-- Timeout

    objHttp.Open(p_action, sUrl, false);

    if (t_fileContent.Length > 0)
        objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + t_multipart_boundary);
    else
    {
        t_fileContent.Append(p_body);
        objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }

    objHttp.Send(t_fileContent.ToString());

    if (objHttp.Status == 200)
        return objHttp.responseText;

    return "";
}
```

You have to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`.

But there are proper .NET classes that handle sending over HTTP. It would be better to rewrite using those.

Comment: The problem is the objHttp doesn't have methods for 'Open', 'setRequestHeader', 'Send', 'Status', or 'responseText'.  See the screenshot in my edit.

Comment: @DrewJackson - Try `dynamic`.

Comment: And, for the record, I would prefer to rewrite using proper c# .net classes, I'm just not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll - there is a 'core' .NET way to do this:

```
public static string Send(string p_ipAddress, string p_action, string p_page, string p_body, string p_filePath)
{
    dynamic objHttp = System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP"));

    objHttp.Open(p_action, sUrl, false);

    if (t_fileContent.Length > 0)
        objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + t_multipart_boundary);
    else
    {
        t_fileContent.Append(p_body);
        objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }

    objHttp.Send(t_fileContent.ToString());

    if (objHttp.Status == 200)
        return objHttp.responseText;

    return "";
}
```